# becomeFirstResponder and estimatedRowHeight incompatibility

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` containing `UITableViewCell` containing an `UITextView`.

I wanted two things :

1. user can enter text in the `UITextView` and its dimension grows according to it.
2. when user click on add button, the `textView` becomes first responder.

1.The first aim has been implemented as :

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

and it works well

2.For the second thing, I simply wrote :

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.cellTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    cell.cellTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

and it does not work... :-(

What is even more bizarre, is that if I delete the first block of instructions above (in particular the `estimatedRowHeight` instruction), the `becomeFirstResponder` works well.

Do you have any clue to perform both functionalities ?
Thanks !

Comment: You aren't getting the cell from your table. You are dequeuening/creating new cell.

Comment: 1. where is your button in hierarchy, inside cell? 2. where do you take indexPath?

Comment: 1. the button is outside the tableview
2. sorry, I have deleted some lines of the function. I will update it

Comment: Desdenova, it seems you are right, thank you !!! I have spend many hours on this problem. Please send it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for get cell:

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false) // add this line if you wish to scroll for input
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MyCell {
        view.endEditing(true)
        cell.cellTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```